# The Mysql database vanished and there is no more user

Tags: mysql, recovery

I have an ubuntu production server running Mysql, i changed the datadir to this :

```
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /srv/datadisk02/dbs
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
innodb_use_sys_malloc = 0
```

The db was created like this :

```
CREATE DATABASE sport;CREATE USER admin; SET PASSWORD FOR admin = PASSWORD('*****');GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sport.* TO admin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '****'; exit;
```

After that the credential were given to Wordpress, I did not interact directly with mysql. All of this was done a week ago, and everything worked perfectly until now.

Since a few hours the mysql is empty. The admin user does not exist anymore, and the db has vanished.

I have mysql logs at /var/log and /var/log/mysql/ and they are all empty except /var/log/mysql/error.log :

```
150310  8:29:35 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150310  8:29:35 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150310  8:29:35 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150310  8:29:35 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150310  8:29:35 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
150310  8:29:35 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150310  8:29:35 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
150310  8:29:35  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
150310  8:29:35  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
150310  8:29:35  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
150310  8:29:36  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150310  8:29:39 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 0
150310  8:29:39 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
150310  8:29:39 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
150310  8:29:39 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
150310  8:29:39 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150310  8:29:39 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.41-0ubuntu0.12.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
150310  9:16:03 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

150310  9:16:03 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
150310  9:16:03  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
150310  9:16:04  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
150310  9:16:04 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

What happend? what can i do? is my work all gone?

Comment: Are you saying you changed the data directory but didn't move the existing data?

Comment: No, i changed the directory before my initial wordpress install. Between th DB creation and finishing the wordpress yesterday i did not interact with Mysql. I woke up to wordpress unable to connect to DB.

Comment: @Syl are there any cron jobs which could have upgraded mysql or your version manager's packages?

Comment: Server Install is from the 3 of this month. Crontab -e is empty. I recreated another DB, and i noticed that it create a folder with the DB name, the deleted DB folder is not present.

Comment: After the changes you did in mysql's config file, did you restart mysql service? Or you proceeded with the wordpress db creation and stuff?

Comment: `InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:...` says that this in an initial installation.  Or the datadirectory was removed.

Comment: Damn.. you were right ypercube. I installed my server, configured mysql and apache, and forgot to restart mysql... The data was in the default folder, so after one week it restarted and used an empty directory. At least now I know it is very easy to move datadir :/ Post a answer if you want the upvote.